# user logouts when other application's user logged in issue C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I am using two separate applications in `chrome` browser after logged in both applications with their respective users of same `Role`, when I logged out from one application, other application's user also logged out automatically. Its very strange cause there is no relation between these both applications. I am using `MembershipProvider` in both applications.

Please help to figure out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very similar issue: http://forums.asp.net/t/1719755.aspx?Membership+provider+authentication+shared+between+two+websites

It was solved by changing the `machineKey` in `web.config` for one of the applications.